# Function within function 3 times over in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am kinda new to Javascript and have written some Chrome Extension. The code contains a sequence process where one function is being passed to another and will be called when the first is done. To be frank, this is getting complicated for me to even look at.

I will explain with an example that shows the sequence I have in my code:

```
function successFunc() {
    console.log("Success!");
}

function handleErrorFunc(successFunc) {
    ... stuff to handle error...
    step1(successFunc);
}

function step1(successFunc) {
    var url = ...
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
    request.onerror = function() {
        ...
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            ...
            step2(successFunc)
        }
    }
}


function step2(successFunc) {
    var url = ...
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
    request.onerror = function() {
        ...
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            ...
            successFunc()
        }
    }
}
```

Now I call

```
step1(successFunc);
```

Is there something to prevent this from happening, some design pattern perhaps?

Comment: Maybe look into promises?

Comment: As @mplungjan said, alternatively look at callbacks, if you've got a lot of levels in your sequence make sure you don't end up in so called 'callback hell' :)

Comment: @mplungjan promises, can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many javascript libraries return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from an ajax call. This is a preferable method to using callbacks as it neatens your code considerable.

Instead of the code you currently have, your code would instead look like this.

```
step1().then(step1Result => step2(step1Result))
      .catch(err => console.error("step1 faled",err));
```

You can continue to chain this as appropriate

```
step1().then(step1Result => step2(step1Result)
                             .then(step2Result => step3(step2Result))
                             .catch(err => console.error("step2 failed",err))
      )
      .catch(err => console.error("step1 faled",err));
```

Using the standard `XMLHttpRequest` does not follow this pattern, but it is straightforward to wrap in a Promise if thats what you want to do - however it is much easier to use an existing ajax library which supports promises.

I would suggest you start by reading [Using Promises guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

---

edit: If you want to wrap your calls in an `Promise` make sure you pass back the response as well as the errors. eg:

```
function ajaxGet(url){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
        request.onerror = reject; // will pass back error
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) {
                resolve(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then `step1` might be

```
function step1(){
    return ajaxGet("url/for/step1");
}
```

Comment: what exactly is `step1Result` please? Edit: ho OK it is a lambda expression, so I guess this should be simply `() => step2()` if step1 is a void function, right?

Comment: @ofekp exactly what it says on the tin - the result of the ajax call in `step1`. I presume you actually want to get some response from your ajax calls?

Comment: Correct, but out of curiosity, `() => step2()` for void, and `step1Result => step2(step1Result)` to process a non void step1?

Comment: @ofekp yes, that makes more sense. See update there as well as edit to show how I would personally wrap your ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at is *promises* in Javascript. But before you dive into something that specific I would recommend you get a basic understanding of *functional programming* in Javascript.

A few links to help you out in this case are given below -

[Functional Programming in JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84)

[Promises in JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=104J7_HyaG4)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to your problem is to use promises :

```
function successFunc() {
    console.log("Success!");
}

// now returns a promise and does not need successFunc
function step1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", 'your/url', true);
        request.send();
        request.onerror = function() {
            reject();
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                resolve();
            }
        }
    });
}


// now returns a promise and does not need successFunc
function step2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", 'your/url', true);
        request.send();
        request.onerror = function() {
            reject();
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                resolve();
            }
        }
    });
}

function handleErrorFunc(step) {
    if (step === 1) {
        // handle step1 errors...
    }
    else if (step === 2) {
        // handle step2 errors...
    }
}

// chain your step calls
step1()
.then(() => {
    step2()
    .then(() => {
        successFunc();
    })
    .catch(() => {
        handleErrorFunc(2);
    });
})
.catch(() => {
    handleErrorFunc(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that's much better! Can you show how to add 'handleErrorFunc' to this?

Comment: I thought `handleErrorFunc` is your main code function since it's the one calling step one. If it's not the case, can you explain its purpose and why does it have `successFunc` as argument ?

Comment: I assume you want to handle the errors from both steps, and your main code is where your functions are defined. I will update my response with that.

Comment: Your calls to `resolve` ignore the response and your calls to `reject` ignore the error. Thats going to make using this *very* hard indeed. One reason why the OP should use an existing library rather than trying to wrap calls to XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I know, I was just answering him to the extent of his question, maybe he does not need neither the response nor the error, which would be fairly easy to incorporate to the `XMLHttpRequest` without the need for whatever libraries you had in mind.

Comment: @Jamiec What library are you suggesting? I kinda like this answer since I see how I should incorporate my code in it, though, I will be glad to not have to duplicate the XMLHttpRequest code every time if you have a suggestion.

Comment: @ofekp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks has a list.